# Could not load user defined filter in web.xml ... WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72

Tags: java, weblogic

Weblogic 10.3.6
JDK 1.7
Eclipse Luna

I have seen errors where the bean is already loaded and it errors out when the bean is attempted to load again. In the below scenario, It is unable to load it at all.
Following error when Weblogic server startup:

```
<BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:.../war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:.../war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - zip:.../war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 2):

Identified a duplicate jar in the deployment which was causing a collision and not load the configuration at all. Set the dependency jar scope to 'provided' and the maven build now has only one version of the jar in the deployment EAR.

Comment: this did the job for me

Comment: @chiti-dahan I am glad it helped.

Comment: Could you please share the name of those conflicting jars? I have similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058669/could-not-load-user-defined-filter-in-web-xml-com-xxx-corsfilter